# When comparing types/classes, is it "safe" to use the 'is' operator instead of the '==' operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, types, subclass

I don't think this is a duplicate, as I'm asking about `is` vs `==` in the **specific case** of comparing types, but please let me know and I will remove the question.

I know that the `is` operator in python really translates to `id(type(a))==id(<type>)`; but so far, I've found `type(a) is <type>` seems to give predictable results. My question is, **would using the `is` operator ever yield an unexpected result** (i.e. something like `'foo' is str` returning `False`)? Or does python store `type` classes at predictable locations, so that `is` will always give the same result as `==`? I find `is` is somewhat more readable in this context.

Note this case is if I'm **not dealing with inherited classes/subclasses** (in which case `isinstance` would be suitable).

Comment: Don't think of `is` as an `id` comparison. `a is b` evaluates to `True` if `a` and `b` are the same object. If that's what you're looking for, go ahead and use it.

Comment: In particular, memory locations are entirely irrelevant. In Python implementations other than CPython, they might even change in the middle of the expression (though `id` values wouldn't).

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, I've heard that explanation in multiple stackoverflow threads; I guess only in limited contexts, those operations are equivalent.

Comment: a class is also an object of type `type`. In Python -- everything is an object -- so I *think* it should be safe.

Comment: Well, if the context is CPython, that's valid, although, it is an implementation detail (one unlikely to change, but you still shouldn't rely on it).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're asking the same thing I've investigated a couple of years ago, which `Blckknght` answered well.  If your question is different, feel free to comment here and let me know and I'll reopen this.

Comment: @wim Thanks, didn't see that thread. Then the answer to my question (embedded in his broader question) is "As for getting two different references to the same class at different memory locations, that's not really possible due to Python's object semantics." -- i.e. `is` should work on identical `type`s. Right?

Comment: Yes, because that's what `__eq__` actually uses.  Most of the time you want `isinstance` instead, but you seem to be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

No, using `is` always does the same thing, it compares (in (C)Python) the address of the objects you've supplied. No redefining of `is` possible so you always get the same behavior.

If two objects `a` and `b` have the same object as their type, using `type(a) is type(b)` will *always* return `True`. In reverse, if `type(a) is type(b)` it is guaranteed that their types will match.

`==` on the other hand can lead to unexpected results if someone comes around and defines an `__eq__` that does silly things:

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    pass

f1, f2 = Foo(), Foo()
```

Now:

```
type(f1) == type(f2)
False
```

but:

```
type(f1) is type(f2)
True
```

People won't do something like that though, it's plain silly. So `type(f1) == type(f2)` doesn't guarantee anything (for non built-ins, that is).

In general, if you care that they are the exact same object (as noted in a comment) use `is`, if you care that they have been designed to behave the same way (for which you'd expect an equivalent `__eq__` to be implemented) use `==`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Addresses types? `is` (leading to `id`) doesn't care about what you give it, it behaves the same way. `==` which leads to `__eq__` doesn't care if it's an instance or a class or a metaclass, it can still have a weird implementation that leads to unexpected results. Maybe I misunderstood the question? I'm not sure.

Comment: Well *the question* is about types. And how to check them. I think he's wondering whether it's possible that object `a` has type `t` but `type(a) is t` returns `False`.

Comment: Better but still not really answering the question, I think. You talk about *"If two objects a and b have the same object as their type"* but should talk about *"If two objects a and b have the same type"*.